# Zend - Changing Identity information without relogging

Tags: forms, zend-framework, zend-framework2, identity

I have a form where the user can change his profile information, but when he does that the nickname is changed in the DB while the old nickname is still showing in the page. How can I refresh the identity info without the need of relogging ?

Comment: Have you tried calling `authenticate` method from the auth service? I might do that, depending on what auth service are you using.

Comment: Nickname is something I save in the $session variable, thus if the user change it, Iupdated in the $session->user->nickname and that it the value I show in the dashboard of the application. Give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

what I do is after the update, I added these:

```
$authService = new AuthenticationService();
$userRow = $this->getUsersTable()->getUserRow($getIdentity->user_id); //get user row from table
$authService->getStorage()->write($userRow); //Re-write session storage
```

not sure if it's the best way, but it works for me.